# Adobe Air 3.3 or AS3: Dynamic variable to search xml

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5

I am using Flash CS6 - Adobe AIR 3.3:
Instead of typing exactly what I'd like to search for in my XML, I'd like to use a dynamic variable that can be changed to search for different categories and days.  The following is  something like the code I'd like to use:

```
var someCategory:String = new String("food");
var someDay:String = new String("monday");

var locationsLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
locationsLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.myfile.xml"));
locationsLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, init);

//load xml

function init(e:Event):void
{
theXML = new XML(e.target.data);
theXML.ignoreWhitespace = true;
e.currentTarget.close();

for(var i:int = 0; i < theXML.someCategory.length(); i++) 
{
if(theXML.someCategory[i].somdDay != "un")
{
//do soemthing
}
}
```

This code works currently ONLY if I actually type "food" and "monday" in the 'for' and 'if' loop.  Any suggestions?

The XML would be...

```
<xml>
<food>
<monday>yes</monday>
</food>
<food>
<monday>yes 2</monday>
</food>
<food>
<monday>un</monday>
</food>

</xml>
```

Here's what currently works:

```
var someCategory:String = new String("food");
var someDay:String = new String("monday");

var locationsLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
locationsLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.myfile.xml"));
locationsLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, init);

//load xml

function init(e:Event):void
{
theXML = new XML(e.target.data);
theXML.ignoreWhitespace = true;
e.currentTarget.close();

for(var i:int = 0; i < theXML.food.length(); i++) 
{
if(theXML.food[i].monday != "un")
{
//do soemthing
}
}
```

Comment: You have lots of errors in your code can you please correct, for example somDay, I and someCategory should this be typed as String or is it an Array?  where are days in your XML?  Show the code that works for you as well.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Yes, they are strings.  I fixed the XML, and showed what currently works.

Comment: Thanks for correcting see my answer below, believe this serves your purpose fine, ignore the fact that I put the XML inline and got rid of the Loader etc, just did it for ease of checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied your code and stepped through changing each part step by step and seemed to get the same result with each change I made so I believe what's below is correct.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class TestAS3Project extends Sprite
    {
        public var theXML:XML = new XML(<xml>
                <food>
                    <monday>yes</monday>
                </food>
                <food>
                    <monday>yes 2</monday>
                </food>
                <food>
                    <monday>un</monday>
                </food>

            </xml>);
        public function TestAS3Project()
        {
            init();
        }
        private function init():void
        {

            var someCategory:String = new String("food");
            var someDay:String = new String("monday");

            theXML.ignoreWhitespace = true;

            for(var i:int = 0; i < theXML[someCategory].length(); i++) 
            {
                if(theXML[someCategory][i][someDay] != "un")
                {
                    //do soemthing
                    trace(theXML[someCategory][i][someDay]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - putting the variables in brackets fixed it.  Was driving me nuts!

Comment: No problem please accept if you can and it resolves your issue.  There's a good site on E4X here http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withflashcs3/?page=4 I was just going on previous knowledge that you can access members of a class using square brackets if you need to use a string when accessing/calling.

Comment: It's probably better long term to use elements(), rather than the node name in brackets, since if you wind up having a node that lacks a child node with the given name, it will blow up.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship you can still have some issues with `elements`, I have found.  It is useful to put a conditional check against `hasOwnProperty` to limit results.  An example from a project I am working on, where `xmlID` is a variable:  `xml..someData.(@id == xmlID).(hasOwnProperty("@frameOffset")).@frameOffset.toString()`.  This result still provides valid empty output even if the data does not exist.  If I were not sure that every `someData` element had an `id` attribute, then I could put another `hasOwnProperty` check in the chain there.

Comment: I usually walk down the tree, checking for a valid node at each point, and then go with String(finalNode@childName), which will either be null or have my stuff in it. Similar idea. Your expression would fail if not all someData nodes have an id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a conditional statement and use a `for each` loop instead of a `for` loop:

```
var cat:String = new String("food");
var day:String = new String("monday");

for each (var node:XML in theXML[cat].(child(day) != 'un')) {
    trace(node[day]);
}
```

The `theXML[cat].(child(day) != 'un')` part means

> (loop) for each children of **theXML** with node name **[cat]** having child node with node name **[day]** the value of which is not 'un'.